# Adapter does not update the NetworkImage in Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using recycler view and in the recycler view I have networkImage. I am trying to load image from gallery as follows, but it does not load it, it still uses the default image. I have tested and validated url is valid. I wonder what I am missing. Initially, I have an image is loaded, and now I am trying to update it.

**ItemData Class**

```
public class ItemData {

private String url;

public ItemData(String url){

    this.url = url;
}

String getUrl(){return url;}
void setUrl(String t){url = t;}
}
```

**In the Activity**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
       Uri filePath = data.getData();
       Update(getRealPathFromURI(filePath));
     }
}

private void Update(String path)
{
    // update the existing view
    listImages.set(0, new ItemData(path));
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int pos) {
  int position = pos;
  ImageUtil.setPic(viewHolder.imgViewIcon, itemsData.get(position).getUrl());
}
```

**ImageUtil Class**

```
public static void setPic(NetworkImageView imageView, String picturePath) {
        // Get the dimensions of the View
        int targetW = imageView.getWidth();
        int targetH = imageView.getHeight();

        if(targetW != 0 || targetH != 0)
        {
            // Get the dimensions of the bitmap
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, bmOptions);
            int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
            int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;

            // Determine how much to scale down the image
            int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetW, photoH / targetH); // zero division olasiligi...

            // Decode the image file into a Bitmap sized to fill the View
            bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
            //bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, bmOptions);

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.postRotate(getImageOrientation(picturePath));
            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
                    bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);

            imageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
        }
    }
```

Here is the bitmap screenshot, as seen below, it is not null.

[image]

Comment: You are updating image in recyclerView successfully but i think you can't update ImageUtil Class imageview from onBindViewHolder in this way . you should use onItemClickListner on recyclerView

Comment: In addition to the other commenst, targetW and targetH are surely both 0 in your code. That's because imgViewIcon was not measured yet when you try to use setPic.

Comment: I have just checked and it is 150 and 150, it is not 0. the following line is getting called in the ImageUtil class `imageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);`

Comment: But in the recycler view, I have two items, one of them is `networkimageview` and the other one is `Imagebutton`. How could I detect `networkImageView` is clicked in the `onItemClickListener` on `RecyclerView`? Because when you click on `networkimageview` is an action to add a new image, when you click on `Imagebutton` is an action to delete that clicked recycler view.

Comment: Looks strange size is defined, because when `onBindViewHolder` is executed views are not measured yet. BTW for handling click you need your ViewHolder to implement `OnClickListener` interface and get the item position with `getAdapterPosition` method. In this way you can work on the specific item.

Comment: You are right, view is not there at that moment, but event though I am updating the existing view, same thing happen. It does not update the image at all, I could observe valid bitmap. Could you please give me an example of how I am getting differentiate which item is clicked in the OnClicListener on RecyclerView? I would be glad if you provide a sample of code.

Comment: [This](https://gist.github.com/thetonrifles/93f69a18bb1f05c06e52) is just an example of how to handle click on a specific element. Hope could be helpful.

Comment: @casillas :- I am not sure exactly where is the problem but if you are able to get correct url inside onBindViewHolder() function then there will be problem with "ImageUtil". And your are doing it in a very traditional way, why don't you try http://square.github.io/picasso/ lib. It's quite easy to use. Just for a test just use picasso inside onBindViewHolder() function.

Comment: @casillas :- Add Picasso in your dependency and replace "ImageUtil.setPic(viewHolder.imgViewIcon, itemsData.get(position).getUrl());" code with 
    Picasso.with(context)
    .load(itemsData.get(position).getUrl())
    .placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder)//your place holder if any
    .into(viewHolder.imgViewIcon);

Comment: I have already done a lot of NetworkImage in my code, it is too late to move on the Picasso at the moment.

Comment: @thetonrifles, thanks a lot for the source code share, but still could not able to update the image.

Comment: @casillas Ok, maybe it could be useful to simplify scenario a bit. Instead of using NetworkImage code with transformations applied to the Bitmap, try to just set a Drawable. If it works move step by step to your scenario. I can try to reproduce your situation. Just I need little time. From you I would just need some info more on code you use for picking your image when clicking on Button.

Comment: @thetonrifles, I would be glad if you could help me out further.

Comment: @casillas I started creating project with code that should be similar to yours [here](https://github.com/thetonrifles/stackoverflow/tree/so-35403081). Right now I'm not using volley. I'm starting just by creating a RecyclerView with elements including an ImageView and a Button. I need first of all to understand the flow you are following for setting the Bitmap. As far as I understood you have default image urls and update images with picker from gallery, right?

Comment: Yes, my initial url is coming from the following         `ItemData itemsData[] = {new ItemData("http://media.caranddriver.com/images/media/51/2016-10best-cars-lead-photo-664005-s-original.jpg")};`

Comment: I will be out for 6-7 hours, and will be back. sorry for the inconvince.

Comment: @casillas ok no problem. I will update code in the meanwhile.

Comment: @casillas I've updated code for integrating Volley. Without any transformation applied to image I can load from url properly (you can see it if you launch the sample app). Unfortunately it seems your link doesn't work. I see 404 Not Found if I try opening it. BTW we can move discussion to chat. It's probably better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103468/discussion-between-thetonrifles-and-casillas).

Comment: @thetonrifles, we are very close to get it down. The sample project that you provided is very close to mine. I could able to load the first image in my project as well. The problem that I am currently facing, I have added onclicklistener to the NetworkImageView, and when I click on the NetworkImageView, dialog show up and I pick the image from the gallery to replace the clicked image. But no matter what I choose from the gallery, image does not get updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/thetonrifles/stackoverflow/tree/so-35403081) on GitHub I put code with the entire flow implemented.

Main problem is the usage of `NetworkImageView` for rendering local images.

You can extend `NetworkImageView` as follows and use method `setLocalImageBitmap` in case you need to load local images into your view.

```
public class MyImageView extends NetworkImageView {

    private Bitmap mLocalBitmap;

    private boolean mShowLocal;

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setLocalImageBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            mShowLocal = true;
        }
        this.mLocalBitmap = bitmap;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageUrl(String url, ImageLoader imageLoader) {
        mShowLocal = false;
        super.setImageUrl(url, imageLoader);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {

    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    if (mShowLocal) {
            setImageBitmap(mLocalBitmap);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @casillas I can try to check today for reproducing problem.

Comment: Here is the actual question that we discussed today, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35493756/recycler-networkimageview-scrolling-back-and-forward-out-of-memory-and-resizing

Answer (score 0):

You should set the new ArrayList in the adapter.
Make a method in BaseAdapter
In Activity,

```
listImages.add(new ItemData(path));
adapter.setNewList(your arraylist);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And In Adapter,

```
public void setNewList(Arraylist<String> newlist)
{
this.list=newlist.
}
```

It will do your all work.